# Monitoring an incoming SMS with Toast

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to monitor an incoming sms in a phone by making a Toast message pop up when a sms is received. However, with the following code, I don't receive the Toast message even when a sms is received. Why is that so? I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and there are no errors when I run the code.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="mapp.com.sg.broadcastreceiver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;

    private BroadcastReceiver the_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message Received!", duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    };

    private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Register receiver if activity is in front
        this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister receiver if activity is not in front
        this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Android 4.1 Jelly Bean (API 16) so is this why I can't receive the Toast message?

Comment: It works now! It's only because I didn't set the app permissions properly that it didn't quite work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as following by adding the receiver in the manifest file

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.SMSReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

and then create SMSReceiver class

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;

        if (myBundle != null) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message Received!",duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do I have to change my existing code besides the manifest file? Because I tried your code and the message is still not showing

Comment: The code I  have mentioned above should work definitely because that's all I'm using in my application. Also im not sure how your logic works, since you have registered the receivers in some Activity (I'm bit confused). Just add a breakpoint inside in the onReceive code of mine and see if its triggering it.

Comment: It works now! It's only because I didn't set the app permissions properly that it didn't quite work out.